# Access to cell attributes with row id

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have the following table and jQuery code to create an object based on some columns/cells data-attributes:

```
<tbody>
    <tr id="1">
        <td data-name1="Name 1">Name 1</td>
        <td data-name2="Name 2">Name 2</td>
        <td data-name3="Name 3">Name 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
        <td data-name1="Name 1">Name 1</td>
        <td data-name2="Name 2">Name 2</td>
        <td data-name3="Name 3">Name 3</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Right now I have stored all the tr id's in a variable so I have this jQuery code:

```
for (var x = 0; x < idsVar.length; x++) {
    var tdName1 = $(`#${idsVar[x]} > td`).attr('data-name1');
    var tdName2 = $(`#${idsVar[x]} > td`).attr('data-name2');
}
```

This code seems to work. The problem is that now I'm implementing [jQuery DataTables](https://datatables.net/) library with default pagination and the problem I'm facing is that for example; if my table contains more than 1 page the above code only works for the rows on the current page, if I want to access to the rows from other page they doesn't exists for my jQuery code.

I was reading the DataTables documentation and seems that this code could help:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
table.rows().nodes().etc...
```

But I think that code loops throught all the table rows and what I'm trying to do is only on some specific row ids. So my question is how can I access to a specific row id and some data attributes. Maybe something like:

```
table.rows('specificId').nodes('data-attribute') 
or 
table.rows('specificId').nodes().something to get the data attribute
```

Comment: Your code doesn't work. It sets `tdName2` to `undefined`. `.attr()` gets the attribute of the first element in the collection, which is the one with `data-name1`. You need to use ```$(`#${idsVar[x]} > td[data-name2]`)``` to get the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access to a specific row by its ID you can use this:

```
var row = table.row('#idHere')
```

And for access to the data attributes of that row you can use this:

```
var row = table.row('#idHere').nodes()[0];
$(row).attr('data-attributeName');
```

Please go to [datatable docs](https://datatables.net/reference/type/row-selector) for more information.